# External CA Signed certificate installation using bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, certificate, ca

I configured an openssl CA. I generated a CSR from another device's bash and signed using my openssl CA. I copied the signed cert to the device. Now I want to use this certificate while doing SSH to the device. How can I make use of this CA signed cert instead of default self signed certificate?

Comment: In what kind of context are you using these certificates? apache? nginx? apt? ssh?

Comment: You want to use the signed certificate as the ssh host key?

Comment: @StianSkjelstad nginx. Also it will be great  if you could help me to understand how it works wrt to Apache and ssh.

Comment: I updated the nginx.config file with new private key and signed certificate. And it's working. I would like to do that from console directly instead of editing config file. Is there any nginx specific command that could help me?

Comment: Short answer no. nginx depends on editing of config-files. The config files behaves as script, and they support variables etc. But there probably exists some config file generators, but in general you have to edit those config files manually